# How to make the right side equal to the left side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Line 2 is me attempting it until,I stumble upon 4^n.
I don't know how to simplify this to be a base of 2.

Comment: Is that curl-thing a "$2$" or an "$a$"?

Comment: $\frac12=2^{-1}, 4^n=(2^2)^n=2^{2n}.$

Comment: Do you want a solution for $n$? Please write your question properly. Because it is true for all $n$. So, I don't understand what you mean by 'make equal'.

Comment: I don't think $2^{n^{2} }= (2^{n})(2^{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe $4^n = 2^{(2 n)}$ so on t he RHS the $4^n$ and $2^{(-2 n)}$ cancel out. What remains is

$$
2^{n^2} = \frac{1}{2} 2^{n^2 +1}
$$

which is obviously true.

Answer (score 0):

$2^{n^2}\neq (2^n)\cdot (2^n)$ so here's the answer

$2^{n^2}=2^{-1}\cdot 2^{2n} \cdot 2^{n^-2n+1}$ or
$2^{n^2}=2^{-1+2n+n^2-2n+1}$ which is true